# Definite articles with adverb words like "very" and "much"

Tags: articles

Can we use definite articles with adverb words like *as, rather, very, much, quite, so*, and *such*, too?

Which one of these is grammatically correct:

> (A) He is a very good person.
>
> (B) He is the very good person.

Please elaborate.

Comment: They can both be correct. It depends on context.

Comment: He is a very kind person. He is _the_ very kind person _who gave up his seat on the train to you last week_.

Comment: Usually it's (A), but, as others have mentioned, that doesn't mean (B) "isn't grammatically correct," particularly in expanded contexts.

Answer (score 3):

A is correct but B depends on the context.

For example:

> He is the **very good** person I was talking about.

There isn't anything special about using a definite article along with adverbs; the same rules apply here.